# Having a problem with Illustrator script for coloring the stroke of a line and then exporting it in all of the colors in a swatch group

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

The script works, however illustrator resets the stroke size to default before going through the swatch colors and exporting.  Does anyone have any idea why and how to fix this issue?

```
#target illustrator

//get a reference to the the current document

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var mySelection = doc.selection;
var swatches = doc.swatches;

//select a folder to save images into
var savePath = Folder.selectDialog( 'Please select a folder to export swatch images into', '~' );
//exported image dimensions
var width = 100;
var height = 100;
//PNG export options
var pngExportOpts = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
   pngExportOpts.antiAliasing = false;//keep it pixel perfect 
   pngExportOpts.artBoardClipping = false;//use the path's dimensions (setup above), ignore full document size
   pngExportOpts.saveAsHTML = false;
   pngExportOpts.transparency = true;//some swatches might have transparency


//go through the swatches


for(var i = 0; i < swatches.length; i++){
   //set the stroke colour based on the current swatch colour

   for(var j=0; j<mySelection.length; j++) { mySelection[j].strokeColor = swatches[i].color; }

   //export png
   doc.exportFile( new File( savePath+ '/' + swatches[i].name + '.png'), ExportType.PNG24, pngExportOpts );
   //remove any previous paths (in case of transparent swatches)

   //doc.pathItems.removeAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is resetting the stroke size to default because during the first turn of the loop the stroke color is being set to "`[None]`".

Only attempt to change the stroke color if the current swatch *is not* named "`[None]`".

For instance; you need to change the `for` loop parts in your current script to the following instead:

```js
// ...

// Go through the swatches
for (var i = 0; i < swatches.length; i++) {

  var swatchName = doc.swatches[i].name;

  // Proceed to change stroke color only if the current swatch is not named [None]
  if (swatchName !== "[None]") {

    // Loop through the document selections
    for(var j = 0; j < mySelection.length; j++) {
      mySelection[j].strokeColor = doc.swatches[i].color;
    }

    doc.exportFile( new File( savePath+ '/' + swatchName + '.png'), ExportType.PNG24, pngExportOpts );
  }
}
```

**Note:** You'll need to ensure that you have at least one selected item on the documents ArtBoard before running the script.